# Trying to map a property of an object to a string with AutoMapper

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, lambda, automapper

My object `Box` has the property `SerialNumbers`, which is a list (or ICollection) of `<SerialNumber>` objects. I need each `SerialNumber`'s `.Name` property to be mapped to a string in a list of strings in my `BoxedElectrodesRowModel`.

Here is my code:

```
c.CreateMap<Box, BoxedElectrodesRowModel>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.BoxId, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.BoxID))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.SerialNumbers, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.SerialNumbers))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.DateCreated, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.DateCreated));
```

If you notice in the third line, I'm trying to convert `dest.SerialNumbers` (which is a List of strings in the model) to `src.SerialNumbers` which is an ICollection of `SerialNumber`s. I specifically need the `SerialNumber`'s *name* property, though. I've tried to do `src.SerialNumbers.Name` but LINQ doesn't like that.

My attempt to fix this is to add this code above the previous block:

```
c.CreateMap<SerialNumber, string>()
    .ConvertUsing(src => src.Name);
```

But then I get the error "Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type".

I'm really quite new to AutoMapper and feel like I'm flailing around in the dark. Can someone help me through this?

Answer (score 1):

Just convert your source to list.

```
src.SerialNumbers.ToList()
```

If you need a nested property then select that property first.

```
src.SerialNumbers.Select(t=>t.Name).ToList()
```